# PayPal Adaptive Payments / Chained - Delaying the Primary Receiver Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We're opening a new online marketplace and would like to use PayPal Adaptive Payments.

We want to get the users "approval" for a certain transaction (only one), that can be executed in the future, all the while allowing us ("the service") to take a commission.

I want want to use Chained Payments to pay the primary seller and have our service as the secondary receiver. I would like to ONLY start this chain in the future:

1) Customer "approves" the payment (using regular chained payments, not pre-approvals)
2) After 2 weeks, initiate the payment to the primary receiver and at the same time to the secondary receiver (using chained)

Is this possible? I'm starting to feel that only way to pre-approve a single payment is to request a pre-approval key up front, which I would prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Delayed Chained Payment option that may accomplish what you're after. Have you looked into it yet? It doesn't allow you to delay the payment to the primary receiver though and it seems like that is something you're after.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: After a lot of searching, I came to the conclusion that I will need to use Preapprovals after all.